PowerBI Data Export: Large Matrix Table
BLUF: With the current May 2024 PowerBI Desktop, I can look at a Matrix Visual in Reports, and export as CSV the complete expanded table. But PBI chops the table at 10K rows, and the table when expanded is several hundred thousand rows. Looking for a solution.
Your first question is what we have tried, and why are we not using PBI in the cloud. (in other words, are these guys crazy/stupid?)
Background:
MSFT makes available the Call Quality Dashboard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cqd-what-is-call-quality-dashboard only as a PowerBI Desktop feature. It cannot run in the cloud.
The reason seems to be that this connects via (XMLA?) via a custom connector to an OLAP data warehouse. It only works in DirectMode, and does not support most DAX expressions.
We tried following the tip at: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/2021/06/how-to-export-more-than-30000-rows-of-data-from-power-bi-desktop/ to use DAX Studio, and we extended the query to handle more than 10K rows, but we still get clipped.
It seems to us that the 10K limit is NOT on the server, since when the expand the report, it appears there are more than 10K rows.
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0FilterTable = 
        TREATAS({"First-to-Second"}, 'CQD'[Stream Direction])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable2 = 
        TREATAS({"OK"}, 'CQD'[CDR Response Reason])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable3 = 
        TREATAS({"Server"}, 'CQD'[First UserType])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable4 = 
        TREATAS({"Inside"}, 'CQD'[Second Inside Corp])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable5 = 
        TREATAS({"Wired"}, 'CQD'[Second Network Connection Detail])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable6 = 
        TREATAS({"User",
            "Anonymous"}, 'CQD'[Second UserType])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable7 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('CQD'[Session Type])),
            AND('CQD'[Session Type] IN {"Conf"}, SEARCH("Conf", 'CQD'[Session Type], 1, 0) = 1)
        )

    VAR __DS0FilterTable8 = 
        TREATAS({" : Client",
            "Client : Client",
            "Client : Server"}, 'CQD'[Is Server Pair])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable9 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('CQD'[Packet Utilization])),
            NOT('CQD'[Packet Utilization] IN {"(Blank)",
                "062: [0 - 0]",
                "064: [1 - 2)"})
        )

    VAR __DS0FilterTable10 = 
        TREATAS({"NonTest"}, 'CQD'[Test Call Type])

    VAR __DS0FilterTable11 = 
        FILTER(
            KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('CQD'[End Time])),
            AND('CQD'[End Time] >= DATE(2024, 6, 7), 'CQD'[End Time] < DATE(2024, 7, 19))
        )

    VAR __DS0Core = 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
            ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL(
                ROLLUPGROUP(
                    'CQD'[Second Network Name],
                    'CQD'[Date],
                    'CQD'[Day Of Week],
                    'CQD'[Hour],
                    'CQD'[Second Subnet]
                ), "IsGrandTotalRowTotal"
            ),
            __DS0FilterTable,
            __DS0FilterTable2,
            __DS0FilterTable3,
            __DS0FilterTable4,
            __DS0FilterTable5,
            __DS0FilterTable6,
            __DS0FilterTable7,
            __DS0FilterTable8,
            __DS0FilterTable9,
            __DS0FilterTable10,
            __DS0FilterTable11,
            "SumTotal_Call_Count", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Total Call Count])),
            "SumSecond_User_Count", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Second User Count])),
            "SumTotal_Stream_Count", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Total Stream Count])),
            "SumAvg_Call_Duration", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Call Duration])),
            "SumAudio_Poor_Percentage", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Audio Poor Percentage])),
            "SumVideo_Poor_Percentage", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Video Poor Percentage])),
            "SumVideo_Poor_Percentage_Due_to_Freeze", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Video Poor Percentage Due to Freeze])),
            "SumTotal_Call_Dropped_Failure_Percentage", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Total Call Dropped Failure Percentage])),
            "SumAvg_Network_Jitter", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Network Jitter])),
            "SumAvg_Network_Jitter_Max", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Network Jitter Max])),
            "SumAvg_Jitter", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Jitter])),
            "SumP50_Jitter", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[P50 Jitter])),
            "SumAvg_Packet_Loss_Rate", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Packet Loss Rate])),
            "SumAvg_Packet_Loss_Rate_Max", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Packet Loss Rate Max])),
            "SumAvg_Round_Trip", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Round Trip])),
            "SumP50_Latency", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[P50 Latency])),
            "SumAvg_Round_Trip_Max", CALCULATE(SUM('CQD'[Avg Round Trip Max]))
        )

    VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
        TOPN(
            5000002,
            __DS0Core,
            [IsGrandTotalRowTotal],
            0,
            [SumTotal_Call_Count],
            0,
            'CQD'[Second Network Name],
            1,
            'CQD'[Date],
            1,
            'CQD'[Day Of Week],
            1,
            'CQD'[Hour],
            1,
            'CQD'[Second Subnet],
            1
        )

EVALUATE
    __DS0PrimaryWindowed

ORDER BY
    [IsGrandTotalRowTotal] DESC,
    [SumTotal_Call_Count] DESC,
    'CQD'[Second Network Name],
    'CQD'[Date],
    'CQD'[Day Of Week],
    'CQD'[Hour],
    'CQD'[Second Subnet]

